# Partial View cannot be displayed properly after Ajax Submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, jquery

I have the following code which for some reason is not working how I intend it to work.  Basically I found this example online and wanted to adapt it to my needs, however the problem is that I cannot seem to get the ImageList displayed on the page.

The code is as follows :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

            var imageList = $('#imageList');

            //hide the imageList initially
            imageList.hide();

    });

    var Project = {
        save: function () {
            var projectForm = $("#projectForm");
            if (projectForm.valid()) {
                projectForm.submit();
            }
            else {
                Project.onInvalidForm();
            }
        },
        onInvalidForm: function () {
            //CODE FOR INVALID FORM
        },
        onSaveBegin: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE BEGIN
        },
        onSaveSuccess: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE SUCCESS
            $('#imageList').fadeIn('slow');
        },
        onSaveFailure: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE FAILURE
        },
        onSaveComplete: function () {
            //CODE FOR SAVE COMPLETE
            $('#imageList').fadeIn('slow');
        }
    };
</script>


@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "/Create",
    new { },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            OnComplete = "Project.onSaveComplete",
            OnFailure = "Project.onSaveFailure",
            OnSuccess = "Project.onSaveSuccess",
            OnBegin = "Project.onSaveBegin"
    },
    new { id = "projectForm", name = "projectForm" }))
    {
    <div >
```

I cannot seem to point out what is going wrong, and not being able to display the imageList. The code is passing through the `onSaveSuccess: function ()` and also `onSaveCompete: function()` since I did an `alert('')` previously in the code to verify that it is actually passing from there.

Thanks for your help and time

```
@if(Model != null)
{
    @Html.Hidden("hfProjectId", Model.Project.ProjectID)
}

<div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.ProjectTitle)
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project.ProjectTitle)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Project.ProjectTitle)
 </div>
 <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Project.ProjectText)
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Project.ProjectText)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Project.ProjectText)
 </div>
 <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
 </p>
</div>
}


<div id='imageList'>
@{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        if(Model.Project.ProjectID > 0)
        {
            Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/ImageUpload.cshtml", new MvcImageUploaderPartial.ViewModels.ImageModel(Model.Project.ProjectID, 2, "Edit"));
        }
        else
        {
            Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/ImageUpload.cshtml", new MvcImageUploaderPartial.ViewModels.ImageModel(0, 0, "Create"));
        }
    }
}
</div>
```

********** UPDATE ******************************************
Project Controller :-

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Project project)
    {
        ProjectModel viewModel = new ProjectModel();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Projects.Add(project);
            db.SaveChanges();
            viewModel.Project = project;

            return View("Create", viewModel);
        }

        return View(project);
    }
```

ImageController :-

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ImageModel model = new ImageModel();

        return RedirectToAction("Create", "Project", model);
    }

    public ActionResult Save()
    {
        IEnumerable<Image> ImageList;

        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TempData["ProjectId"].ToString()))
        //    iProjId = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["ProjectId"]);

        foreach (string name in Request.Files)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[name];

            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            Image image = new Image(fileName, Request["description"]);
            ImageModel model = new ImageModel();

            ImageList = model.Populate();
            model.Add(ImageList, image, file);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Image");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see in the `AjaxOptions` that you are not passing the `UpdateTargetId`. You should update the code as below,

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(
    "/Create",
    new { },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
            UpdateTargetId = "imageList",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            OnComplete = "Project.onSaveComplete",
            OnFailure = "Project.onSaveFailure",
            OnSuccess = "Project.onSaveSuccess",
            OnBegin = "Project.onSaveBegin"
    }
    //..
```

And one more important thing is the element that you specified in the `UpdateTargetId` should be in the main view not in the partial views that will be returned by the ajax actions. Also, make sure you have reference the unobtrusive ajax library.

Comment: Hi Mark, UpdateTargetId is in the Mian view, ie the Create of the Project, and unobstructive ajax Library is included. When I did as you said, nothing happened, however removeing the "#" did display my Create view 2 times, like a double 1 upon the other one.

Comment: The "#" should not be there sorry :)

Comment: @Johann are you manually replacing the html in the onSaveSuccess from the response? Can you make sure all the required code are included in the post to answer the question.

Comment: Hi Mark, no I am not.  That was a test I made but commented it out before posting.  This is the present code, nothing changed

Comment: Mark I also updated my question with the controller code, maybe it will be easier to spot something. I did not know in the ProjectController "Create" if I had to redirect to the Project "Create" or not

Comment: You are calling the Create action from ajax and isn't it should return a partial view? currently it is returning a complete view which will contain the total html(head, body...). You should return partial views in ajax calls.

Comment: The Create action goes to the ProjectController to create the project, and then I am returning the Create again, which includes a partial view.  The Partial View does not include Headers/Footers etc

Comment: just an update Mark, changed to                 return PartialView("Create", viewModel);
 from the Create and now displaying 2 forms for the create, although there is no header/footer